# c# use user settings in multiple datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, appsettings

I am a new self taught programmer and I feel like there is a better way to accomplish this, so here I am asking.  Thanks.

I have a c# program I am writing, uses windows forms, I have multiple forms with datagridview on them.

I have created another form that allows the user to set preferences about how the view them 
ex: font, background color, alt row color, etc.

So, at each grid I end calling the same code to retrieve these settings, I am just trying to see if there is a more central streamlined approach.

Here is the code I use at each grid to give you a better idea.

```
        //pull the custom user settings for the datagridview
        dgvAds.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.AltRowColor;
        dgvAds.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.RowColor;
        dgvAds.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.RowFont;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way is to call a common function that does these preprarations. You can put it at a level where you can call it from everywhere, like a static `Utlities` class..:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    public static void loadDGVSettings(DataGridView DGV)
    {
        if (DGV != null)
        {
            //pull the custom user settings for the datagridview
            DGV.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = 
                Properties.Settings.Default.AltRowColor;
            DGV.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.RowColor;
            DGV.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.RowFont;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it from each `Form` with the respective `DataGridView`, after maybe `InitializeComponents()`..:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Utilities.loadDGVSettings(dataGridView1);
}
```

To create a class: right-click the project, choose  `add class`, give it the name you like and replace the class stub with code like above. You will need to add a `using System.Windows.Forms;` clause to such a class file.

Comment: thanks - I didnt realize you could update controls like that in classes - works great - thanks again